# Load image to Tab Bar Item from server

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I loaded an image from the server and tried to put it on a `UITabBarItem`, but it just shows a grey square. I already set image render mode to original but does not work...

thank you for your help

```
downloader.imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with: URL(string: GlobalSetting().initUser().photoPath)!, options: .highPriority, progress: { (receivedSize, expectedSize, url) in
            print(receivedSize as Int)
        }, completed: { (image, data, error, success) in
            let newImage = image?.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
            newImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            self.tabBar.items![1].image = newImage
        })
```

GlobalSetting is where I'm saving URL photo "http://api.humancloudz.com/photo/comp_abc/avatar-A18002.png"

Comment: My guess is while you are fetching data (because it is async process) tabbar being already displayed so there is no image reload your view after your fetching image, and if you do that in a UITabbarViewController it would be much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where is the problem in your code as I see only part of it. I tried to create TabBarController, tried to load image in viewDidAppear and everything works fine. Try my code

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png") else { return }
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let image = UIImage(data: data)!
    let resized = resizeImage(image: image, targetSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    tabBar.items![0].image = resized
    tabBar.items![1].image = resized
}

func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let size = image.size
    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

}

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: thankyou very much , you save my day.. maybe im use SDWebImageManager() for download image for my previous code..

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding `DispatchQueue.main.async` when you set the image, like:

```
downloader.imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with: URL(string: GlobalSetting().initUser().photoPath)!, options: .highPriority, progress: { (receivedSize, expectedSize, url) in
        print(receivedSize as Int)
    }, completed: { (image, data, error, success) in
        let newImage = image?.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
        newImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tabBar.items![1].image = newImage
        }
    })
```